# How to list without Ajax page refresh?

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax

I'm listing comments with Ajax, but I want it to be displayed before the page is refreshed as new comments come, can you help?

my ajax code to pull the comment list

```
 // Yorum Listeleme
         $(document).ready(function () {
            let id = $("#BlogID").val();
        $.ajax({
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "Get",
                data: { BlogID: id },
                url: "/Comment/CommentList/",
            success: function (funk) {
                let values = jQuery.parseJSON(funk);
                    let htmlst = ``;
                $.each(values, (index, value) => {
                        htmlst += `<div class="media"><img style="width:64px; height:64px;" src=${value.UserImage} alt="" class="img-fluid" />  <div class="media-body"> <h5 class="mt-0">${value.CommentUserName}</h5><p>${value.CommentContent}</p></div></div>`;
                });
                    $("#listcom").html(htmlst);   
                    
            }
        });
           });
```

My ajax code I wrote to add comments

```
      $("#btncommentadd").click(function () {
            let values = {
                BlogID: $("#BlogID").val(),
                CommentUserName: $("#CommentUserName").val(),
                CommentTitle: $("#CommentTitle").val(),
                CommentContent: $("#CommentContent").val(),
                CommentDate: $("#CommentDate").val()
            };
            $.ajax({
                type: "Post",
                url: "/Comment/CommentAdd/",
                data: values,
                success: function (fnk1) {             
                   let result = jQuery.parseJSON(fnk1);
                    
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. `let values = jQuery.parseJSON(funk);` is not needed, the `funk` results are already usable.

Comment: Hello, I found it nice, thank you for the information. Do you have a solution for my problem?